# SharePoint's Out of The Box "Configure page approval flow" doesn't work after export and import to new enviroment

Tags: sharepoint-online, content-approval

I have created an Approval Workflow using "Configure page approval flow" (Automate > Power Automate > Configure page approval flow). I have made a few updates on it particularly emails and added metadata. It is working as expected on my initial site but when I tried to Import and Export it on a new site in another environment, it does not trigger when I Submit a page for approval.

When I edit the flow, the trigger is set to "For a Selected Item". I am wondering how did this out-of-the-box Approval flow managed to trigger it using "For a Selected Item"?

Note: I have enabled content approval on the new target Site Page library and this is a power automate flow

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Yes, this is by design.**

`For a selected item` will only work on the default environment.
If you customize a flow and import it into a new environment (distinct from the default one), it will not work.

Source: [SharePoint connector -
Known issues and limitations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/connectors/sharepointonline/#known-issues-and-limitations)

> For Flows that use the 'For a selected item' or the 'For a selected
> file' trigger, only those that are part of the default environment in
> Power Automate are listed within the SharePoint Automate menu.

**Workaround to host your flow in a new environment:**

You can change the trigger by something like `When an item is modified` and test the value of a boolean field (`Approval` `Yes/No`): when the approval field is set to true, send the approval in your flow, and change the value to false.

Comment: Thanks jleture.
About if i change the trigger tos omething else will it make any difference?

Comment: Yes, I edit my answer with a workaround, you can change the trigger to not use `For a selected item`